# css-media-queries loading a page

Tags: css

I searched every where on the net, but i couldn't find the answer.
Because I wonder, is it possible to load an website page with the css-media-queries?
So, when he detects screen size, it load up different website page.

***Example:***

He detects a 480px wide screen (mobile screen) and loads up a the website from the css-media-query code that is only made for that screen size with all the php and other functions in it only for that page.

***Is this possible? And what is the best approach to get this done in coding?***

Answer (score 0):

No. Media queries are used for styling content, not loading whole pages. And the backend (i.e. your PHP) script usually has no idea about the client screen size.

basically you have two options:

- Load the content via AJAX after determining viewport size using some JS script
- Set a cookie with the viewport size (again, by a JS script which measures viewport size) and evaluate that in your backend script

But option 2 will only work after the second request, though.